# Concatenate error with Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a URL to access data. Given initial an initial Lat/Lon that will vary from user to user, I want this code to spit out a URL appropriate to access the data.

I keep getting this error: "cannot concatenate 'str' and 'tuple' objects"

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Your `indices=....` line is not creating a string, it's creating a `tuple`

If I do

```
var = 1, 2, 'hello'
```

`var` is not a concatenation of all those things.  It's the tuple: (1,2,'hello')

If you want indices to be a `str`, with all of those things concatenated you can add the following:

```
indices_str = ''.join([str(x) for x in indices])
```

Then you can safely concatenate `path` and `indices_str` by adding them together

Comment: Or replace the commas in the definition of `indices` with `+` to concat them all into a string.

Comment: That assumes that the variables (like `lat_min`) are already stringified